# Nextauth token keeps on nesting

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I updated with v4 beta with `next-auth`. But the token keeps on nesting on refresh, as in token converts to token.token to token.token.token .... on each refresh for some reason

```
jwt: async (token, user, account, profile, isNewUser) => {
      return token; 
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

From version 3 to 4 the default function of jwt changed from

```
async jwt(token, user, account, profile, isNewUser) {
  return token
}
```

to

```
 async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
  return token
}
```

Suggesting that you should take the token out of the first parameter using deconstruction instead of returning the whole thing.